# How to fix "Run-time error 1004, Method "Width" of object "_Application" failed"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that should manage the display size of the Excel workbook when the application is opened and selects a specific worksheet within that workbook.  The hope was to keep as much of the desktop available for other windows/applications.   Two of the worksheets in the workbook are protected, one of those is the worksheet I want displayed when the file is opened. however I don't believe the worksheet has to be unprotected to resize the application window. I added this information because you are smarter than I am.
    I created this code from the developer tab and then selected the "Record Macro".   Initially it worked fine, however i started having problems when presented my workbook to the customer, and they had other excel files already opened.  Now, sometimes, I get the below error when I am only opening a single excel file containing this macro in it.
    When I open the file I get the "Run-time error: '1004': Method "Width" of object "Application" failed".

I am using Excel 2016.
   I think the problem can be solved if the file is selected first or brought to the foreground first but i don't know how to do that (yet), and I have been at this all week trying to figure/find a solution.

Thank you for taking the time to review this.

Following some of the similar issues found here, I tried changing this line of code from:

```
Application.Width = 677.25
```

to:

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.Width = 677.25
```

and it errors. (Run-time error '438':  Object doesn't support the property or method)

The code/macro is in the "ThisWorkbook" file (under the VBAProject, under excel objects).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Width = 677.25
    Application.Height = 663
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    Application.Width = 641.25
    Application.Height = 468
    Sheets("Watch").Select
End Sub
```

The goal of this code was to resize the display of the file when it was opened and to ensure the worksheet "Watch" would be in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Application.WindowState = xlNormal` before you use `Application.Width` or `Application.Height`.

You can't modify the size of the Excel application window if it is maximized.

If your Excel is minimized and the following is true: `Application.WindowState = xlMinimized`, setting width or height won't cause errors, but it also won't have any effect on the window's size even if you later manually change the display from minimized to normal.

Comment: Regret the delay at getting back to you,  I tested it this morning a few times and it works as i hoped.  Brilliant.  Thank you Ryszard!!